# Issue with countdown timer using javascript or php

Tags: javascript, php

I want to run this countdown, but when the countdown finishes, it restarts from 24:00:00. After the countdown finishes, I want to send a message or do something else. How can I do that?

```
<div id="hms">00:00:02</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timeoutHandle;
    function count() {
        var startTime = document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML;
        var pieces = startTime.split(":");
        var time = new Date();    time.setHours(pieces[0]);
        time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
        time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
        var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
        var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
        document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML=newtime;
        timeoutHandle=setTimeout(count, 1000);
    }
    count();

</script>
```

Comment: `timeoutHandle=setTimeout(count, 1000);` will keep on starting a new timer. Please correct me.

Comment: You have to set a condition to continue with a new timeout. If the condition doesn't pass, don't execute the last line in `count` function. See [Control flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Control_flow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just added a counter variable, and when its zero I am clearing the timeout. Have a look https://jsfiddle.net/koh9ca6j/1/

you can add a condition to check when it reaches to zero either by calculating total seconds or any other method.

```
var timeoutHandle;
var counter = 5;

function count() {
  var startTime = document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML;
  var pieces = startTime.split(":");
  //console.log(pieces);
  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(pieces[0]);
  time.setMinutes(pieces[1]);
  time.setSeconds(pieces[2]);
  var timedif = new Date(time.valueOf() - 1000);
  var newtime = timedif.toTimeString().split(" ")[0];
  document.getElementById('hms').innerHTML = newtime;
  counter--;
  if (!counter) {
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    return;
  }
}

function countdown() {
  timeoutHandle = setInterval(count, 1000);
}
countdown()
```

Comment: im trygin to implement that countdown in a table i mean when it reacher zero columns must be in red color is that possble right? btw after your answer how can i send a messagge live "over" or something like that, im pretty noob at this, thanks a lot.

Comment: you can do it before return; in the count() function;

Comment: could you be more specific? I mean
return
if(something)
send something
sorry if im asking a lot

Comment: Updated the jsfiddle link, please check.

Comment: Glad to help, if you still have questions please ask otherwise you can select the answer as [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Comment: <table class="greyGridTable">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>LOG</th>
<th>JOB</th>
<th>HEAT</th>
<th>PROBETA</th>
<th>TIMER</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $log;?></td>
<td><?php echo $job;?></td>
<td><?php echo $heat;?></td>
<td><?php echo $probeta;?></td>
<td><div id="hms">02:00:00</div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

Comment: with that script how can i change the tables colums when the timer is over?

Comment: add this in your problem statement, and what do you want to change ?

Comment: I mean when the timer reaches 0 the table "td" where I echo some variables  should change to some color like red

Comment: Yes you can do that with js and css. add the specific js to the msg() function.

Comment: do you mean here?   msg("Over");

Comment: Let's take this offline: bsaraswat45@gmail.com